# Improve fgetc performance

Tags: c++, c

How can I improve the performance of the following code? The input file is 50GB and the output will be around 500MB.

The code bellow stores in the output the positions where the character '\n' is found on the input.

```
unsigned int char_counter = 0;

FILE *in_file = fopen(input, "rb");
FILE *out_file = fopen(output, "wb");

fwrite(&char_counter, sizeof(int), 1, out_file);

while(char ch = fgetc(in_file))
{
    char_counter++;

    if(ch == '\n') fwrite(&char_counter, sizeof(int), 1, out_file);
    else if(ch == EOF) break;
}

fclose(in_file);
fclose(out_file);
```

Comment: Is it C or is it C++

Comment: @Evan Carslake: I am writing a C++ program so I can use both C and C++.

Comment: well it's not C, and it isn't really C++ either...

Comment: Would this not be more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @IKavanagh: No, I am trying to improve the performance here.

Comment: One byte at a time for 50GB? No wonder it's a dog. Buffering is your friend.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Side note: C != C++. It is one or the other.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Store in the output the positions where the character '\n' is found on the input.

Comment: when calling the fopen() functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @SilverWarrior If you look at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) **performance** is one of the topics that should be brought up on it.

Comment: Perhaps `mmap()` would be of use.

Comment: @ user3629249: This is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to massively increase execution speed, buffer the input.

I arbitrarily used a buffer of 1024 bytes

The following code also correctly checks for errors in opening the files.

I might wonder about the 'b' in the opening mode for the input file, especially since code is checking for newlines.

```
unsigned int char_counter = 0;

FILE *in_file = NULL;
if( NULL == (in_file = fopen(input, "rb") ) )
{ // then, fopen failed
    perror( fopen for input failed:);
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, fopen successful

FILE *out_file = NULL;
if( NULL == (out_file = fopen(output, "wb") ) )
{ // then fopen failed
    perror( "fopen for output failed");
    fclose( in_file ); // cleanup
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, fopen successful

char buffer[1024] = {'\0'};

fwrite(&char_counter, sizeof(int), 1, out_file);

while( fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), in_file ) )
{
    char_counter += strlen(buffer);

    //fwrite( buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, out_file );

    if( strstr( buffer, "\n" ) )
    { // then newline read
        fwrite(&char_counter, sizeof(int), 1, out_file);
    }
}

fclose(in_file);
fclose(out_file);
```

Comment: Note: most files that are formatted with newlines do not have massively long lines.  so the buffer size of 1024 will (usually) not be filled before encountering another newline (the newline will cause the call to fgets() to stop inputting more characters)

Answer (score 4):

To speed-up disk operations use mapping functions (i.e. `mmap()` in *nix or [`CreateFileMapping()` in windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366543(v=vs.85).aspx)). They take care to load pieces of file in memory using disk effective access.
Then handling the checks on local memory will be much faster.

If you want make it by yourself you can access disk using **large enough buffers which dimension must be a multiple of disk sector size**. This will maximize the I/O throughput.

BTW don't think that the `fgetc()` function by itself is so slow, in any case it make use of the File I/O buffering, but reading more sectors in memory (by using a functional memory space in mapping or the correct number of sectors in you code) will boost the result.
Be careful to choose a correct ratio between memory used and speed.

Comment: the OS properly buffers the I/O by sector size, so using a mmap() operation will not be helpful.

Comment: @user3629249 That's why I said that `fgetc()` is not so slow apart from calling, but it should be inlined on a decent system. BTW using mapping you can choose **how much disk to buffer in memory**. This is the point, not the sector size. Moreover mapping functions are OS functions, and they are much much more efficient of C File I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from a big file byte-by-byte using `fgetc( )` is slow. You can improve performance if you read bigger chuncks of data from file, using `fgets( )`.

Try something like this one:

```
#define MAX_BUFLEN (1024)

unsigned int char_counter = 0;

FILE *in_file = fopen(input, "rb");
FILE *out_file = fopen(output, "wb");
char* buffer = (char*)malloc( (MAX_BUFLEN+1) * sizeof(char) );

fwrite(&char_counter, sizeof(int), 1, out_file);


while ( fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFLEN, in_file) )
{
    char_counter += strlen(buffer);
    fwrite(&char_counter, sizeof(int), 1, out_file);
}

free( buffer );

fclose(in_file);
fclose(out_file);
```

Comment: the output file, which will contain nothing but 4byte integers (need to consider the Endian'ness of the underlying CPU architecture for byte ordering) means the output file actually is a binary file

Comment: @user3629249 No problem. I edited the answer. The point of my answer was to read from input file big chuncks of data instead of byte-by-byte.

Comment: the input file (seems) to be text formatted into lines, where each line is terminated via a newline.   The chances of a single line containing 1 meg or more characters is (very nearly) 0.   so the 1 meg buffer is just a waste of resources. A 1k buffer would be sufficient,

Comment: Size of the buffer and where it should be allocated you can choose yourself. I just gave an example how to solve your problem - improve performance.

Comment: I modified the answer again :-)

Comment: the fprintf() of the int value, followed by a newline is changing to contents of the output file, as compared to the OP posted code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87013/discussion-between-kirill-and-user3629249).

Answer (score 0):

To stick to the actual question, improving that code *with* `fgetc`:

```
int input;
do {
 input = fgetc(file);
 if ('\n' == input) {
  // maintain your counter and print
 }
} while (EOF != input);
```

In your original code, you check twice the validity of your read.

But as the other answers already point out, this is quite pointless, since `fgetc` isn't the right tool for this case.

Then again, a possible issue for your code - unrelated to the actual method of input - is that reading and writing are synchronised. If writing blocks, you cannot read in parallel. The easiest solution here, given that the expected output is rather small, would be to buffer a considerable amount and only write from time to time. And of course respect the buffering that is already done by the standard library for you.

Answer (score -2):

The problem here is that you are reading the input file byte by byte.

It would be more efficient to use a RAM buffer to read by chunks of fixed size (ex: 1MB chunks)

Doing things like 1000 successive fgetc() is much slower than doing one single fread() of 1000 bytes.

Memory mapping is also a good solution, but may not be portable on any platform.

Comment: the output is being done (sizeof(int)) bytes at a time, not 1 byte at a time.

Comment: @user3629249 I edited my answer, yours is way better anyway.